# auto scroll down parent div when div grows using css

Tags: css, scroll

I have a parent div which contains many child divs and child divs can also have child.my top parent div contains a scroll bar , if any of the child div grows i want the scroll bar of the parent one to come down to make the grown content visible to the user with out scrolling down.the scroll bar should automatically come down when any of the div grows to make the coontent visible using css.this is the css which i applied on the parent div.

```
.parent{
    width:100%;``
    height:95%;
    overflow-x:auto;
    position:relative
  }
```

Comment: this css i added on the parent div and its child div is growing.i have to scroll down to see the content of the grown child div

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want scroll down to the copyright section of this page.

just right click on this page, click view source and find out the id of the copyright section div.
which is "copyright".

now add this to the current url.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494082/auto-scroll-down-parent-div-when-div-grows-using-css#copyright
```

now hit this url in the browser and see the magic.

Comment: i dont want to append id in the url.I am looking for a way to scroll down using css.